# Put tabular map at text level

Tags: tables, equations, alignment, text

I should write this in LaTeX:
[image]
As you can see the part `$g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$` is at the same level of the rest of the text.
I tried to do it in this way:

```
Se \begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{}}
    $g : $ & $\re \longrightarrow \re$\\
           & $x \longmapsto x$
   \end{tabular}, abbiamo $Y = g(X)$
```

Unfortunately, the result is far from the picture above, in fact:

[image]
Is there any way I can write properly this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabular` has an optional argument precisely for alignment.

Try:

```
Se \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} ll @{}}
    $g : $ & $\re \longrightarrow \re$\\
           & $x \longmapsto x$
   \end{tabular}, abbiamo $Y = g(X)$
```

(If you use `[b]` instead of `[t]` it will align on the bottom row.)

Answer (score 3):

With aligned but in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathds{R}}
\begin{document}
Se $\begin{aligned}[t]
    g \colon   \Reals &\longrightarrow \Reals\\
            x &\longmapsto x
   \end{aligned}$, abbiamo $Y = g(X)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]